# Tumblr Reblog Code Not Working Correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, html, tumblr

I recently installed a tumblr theme but for some reason the reblog button does not work (doesn't do anything on click). Even though the like button works, this one seems to not do anything.

Looking through the code, this is what I see:

```
<div class="metaitemleft topspace" {ReblogButton size="16"}</div>
```

and

```
{block:RebloggedFrom}
     <div class="reblogged metaitemleft">
           <h6>Reblogged from </h6><a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}"><h6>{ReblogParentName}</h6></a>
      </div>
{/block:RebloggedFrom}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `div` misess a `>` (after `topspace"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the template variable on its own, it can't be used as part of the markup for the div:

```
<div class="metaitemleft topspace"> {ReblogButton size="16"} </div>
```

Or just:

```
{ReblogButton size="16!}
```